# How to set borderbrush color to each border direction on different Thickness?

Tags: wpf, border

i used visualbrush on borderbrush for setting different color to each border direction.

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="10,10,5,5" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
      <Border.BorderBrush>
        <VisualBrush>
          <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
              <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
              <Border Background="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
              <Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
            </Grid>
          </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
      </Border.BorderBrush>
  </Border>
```

on xaml, this code did work well. each border direction color is different.
but on behind code,

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.Height = this.rowHeight[r] + topHeight + bottomHeight;
        grid.Width = this.columnWidth[c] + leftWidth + rightWidth;

        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(topHeight) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(rowHeight[r])});
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(bottomHeight) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(leftWidth) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(columnWidth[c])});
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(rightWidth) });


        Border bdTop = new Border() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(cellInfo["BorderBrush"]["Top"]) };
        Border bdBottom = new Border() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(cellInfo["BorderBrush"]["Bottom"]) };
        Border bdLeft = new Border() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(cellInfo["BorderBrush"]["Left"]) };
        Border bdRight = new Border() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(cellInfo["BorderBrush"]["Right"]) };


        bdTop.Height = topHeight;
        bdBottom.Height = bottomHeight;
        bdLeft.Height = this.rowHeight[r];
        bdRight.Height = this.rowHeight[r];


        grid.Children.Add(bdTop);
        grid.Children.Add(bdBottom);
        grid.Children.Add(bdLeft);
        grid.Children.Add(bdRight);

        Grid.SetRow(bdTop, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(bdTop, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(bdTop, 3);

        Grid.SetRow(bdBottom, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(bdBottom, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(bdBottom, 3);

        Grid.SetRow(bdLeft, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(bdLeft, 0);

        Grid.SetRow(bdRight, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(bdRight, 2);

        VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush();
        vb.Visual = grid;
```

if all thickness not same, on behind code, each border direction use each visualbrush. border top showed whole visualbrush. border bottom showed whole visualbrush.

i don't know what's problem....

xaml code used in border UI. behind code used in tablecell border.

Answer (score 1):

if you want want to make a border have 4 different colors you can layer them on top of each other which is a lot more simple to implement:

```
    <Grid Height="50" Width="50">
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5,0,0,0"></Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,5,0"></Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="0,0,0,5"></Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="0,5,0,0"></Border>
        <Grid Margin="5">
           <!-- Content here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, Denis. your Code has work. but i want to use borderbrush to each TableCell on table. TableCell's BorderBrush can't change to grid.... so tablecell set borderthickness(0) and insert Border in tablecell, then very thin space remain between tablecells. i asked other question in overflow. CellSpacing=0 doesn't work, all of borderthickness, magin, padding possible changing set 0 desn't work too... i'm so hopeless now....